# Move range of items in a double linked list? [C]

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct

I want to ask you a suggestion. I have to create a function that swaps the position of two ranges of items (without creating new nodes) in a double `linked list`.

like:

```
ABCDEFG
```

'B','C' swap to 'E','F'

so:

```
AEFDBCG
```

What I was thinking to do, was to change the -

pointer `prec` (previous) of `'B'` `=` pointer `prec` `'E'` and the pointer `succ` (next) of `'C'` `=` pointer `succ` of `'F'`.

Finally the pointer `prec` `'E'` `=` pointer `prec` `'B'` and the `succ` pointer `'F'` `=` pointer `succ` `'C'`.

I've tried to apply what I'm saying But I think that I make many mistakes on the code.

Another way can be to create a function that takes the single item and moves the node to the wanted position.

*Can somebody help me in create a function that does something similar?* My head is going on segmentation fault :P

The struct is like this:

```
struct nodo {
char info;
struct nodo *succ;
struct nodo *prec;
};
typedef struct nodo nodo;
```

Update:

Following the suggestion of Axel I did something like this. For now I'm just swapping one item, after I will iterate this function.
I can't manage to make the debugger working, but i'm trying to solve the problem.

```
nodo *ScambiaSottoliste(nodo *lista,int i,int j){ //I first position, J second position

    nodo *firstRange1, *range1, *metaInf, *metaSup, *range2, *last;

    range1=RicercaPosizione(lista, i); //Reserch position I
    firstRange1=range1->prec;
    metaInf=range1->succ;
    range2=RicercaPosizione(lista, j); //research position J
    metaSup=range2->prec;
    last=range2->succ;

    range1->prec=metaSup;
    range1->succ=last;
    range2->prec=firstRange1;
    range2->succ=metaInf;

return lista;
}
```

Comment: Make two drawings, one before and one after the swap. Highlight the pointers that need to be changed (how many are that?). Then take the drawings to your terminal and type in the code. After that: take care of the corner cases (when one or both of the swapped segments are at the end(s) of the list) Als decide what you want to happen if the segments touch or overlap.

Comment: Use a debugger and step your function and check intermediate values of variables.

Comment: Hmm, if you don't show any code, it is hard to guess where the mistake is ... A common one : if you don't save the value of `pointer prec (previous) of 'B'` before erasing it with `pointer prec 'E'` it is lost when you try to use it to set `pointer prec 'E'`

Comment: @SergeBallesta I've updated the OP with the code.. where do you think i'm doing mistakes?

Comment: Say what are i, j and k, and why k is never used ...

Comment: Swapping single items rather than list ranges is much easier. Single item overlap is directly detectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through your list and split it into five (possibly empty) sub-lists:

1. List before first range
2. First range
3. List after first range and before second range
4. Second range
5. List after second range

During this split you can detect overlaps and the order of the given ranges.
An integer type state variable helps to keep track of the sub-list you are appending to during iteration.

Once you have the sub-lists, you can then join them together in the desired order. Finally, don't forget to maintain your list start and end variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've put a sketch on the OP, can you kindly check it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you are working with a double linked list, you have to change pointers on all the items involved.

So for swapping just 2 items (the provided code) you should have :

```
range1->prec=metaSup;
metaSup->succ= range1;
range1->succ=last;
last->prec = range1;
range2->prec=firstRange1;
firstRange1->succ = range2;
range2->succ=metaInf;
metaInf->prec=range2;
```

But to swap to ranges of nodes, you must only exchange initial and terminal nodes of each range, with a similar technique.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume we want to swap a group of element from between a&b with elements between d&e
Now,
Set the right pointer of a equal to right pointer of d & Set the left pointer of b equal to left pointer of e.  &vice versa
Set the right pointer of group 2 last element points to b
Similarly do the rest